# Why I cannot find the compiled wasm file?

Tags: rust, webassembly, rust-wasm

I am new to the WASM world. I tried to create a really simple rust lib that only contains add function and wants to compile it to the `.wasm`. I already know that the `wasm-pack` can achieve this. But why the `cargo build --target wasm32-unknown-unknown --release` can not?

```ini
// Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "hello-wasm"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
```

```rs
// lib.rs
pub fn add(left: usize, right: usize) -> usize {
    left + right
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        let result = add(2, 2);
        assert_eq!(result, 4);
    }
}
```

The compiled target folder:

```bash
$ ls target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/                 
build/  deps/  examples/  incremental/  libhello_wasm.d  libhello_wasm.rlib
```

Expected there is a file named `hello-wasm.wasm`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a `lib.rs` and no customization, you've defined a Rust library. By default, Cargo compiles libraries to `.rlib` files which can then be used as inputs when compiling crates that depend on this one.

In order to get a `.wasm` file, you must request a `crate-type` of `cdylib` in your configuration (and this is also standard when using `wasm-pack`):

```ini
[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]
```

If you want the library to also be usable in tests and as a dependency, then you should specify the default mode `"lib"` too:

```ini
[lib]
crate-type = ["lib", "cdylib"]
```

(`cdylib` stands for "C dynamic library" — a WASM module is kind of like a dynamic library, and "C" should be understood as just meaning "native format, no Rust-specific conventions".)